# 'Geometric difference' in Google's 'Power of data in quantum machine learning' paper

Tags: machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

Has anyone ever tried to implement the **geometric difference** metric introduced in the Google's [power of data paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01938)? It is defined in Eq. 5.

[image]

My implementation of the metric is as follows.

```
def geometric_difference(kernel_1, kernel_2):
#     diff = -1
    diff = np.sqrt(np.linalg.norm( 
        np.matmul(np.matmul(np.sqrt(kernel_2), 
                            np.linalg.inv(kernel_1)), 
                  np.sqrt(kernel_2)), np.inf))
    
    return diff
```

I understand that when I compute the geometric difference of a kernel matrix with itself, it should give $1$.

However, I am getting $3.5425853205393496$ which is greater than $1$ for the following matrix.

```
M = np.array([[1.0, 0.9864463445333996, 0.9740668604480669, 0.9522423474912594, 0.9924537684077833, 0.8895864607254809, 0.8911800123689296, 0.9273022835638276, 0.9093065295855488, 0.942937484839194], [0.9864463445333996, 1.0, 0.9362292204642889, 0.9058183417109515, 0.9720042335801492, 0.8236054328646096, 0.8311148112692656, 0.873310656326527, 0.8563983095457245, 0.9095079241006527], [0.9740668604480669, 0.9362292204642889, 1.0, 0.9251948438121138, 0.9922213493721925, 0.9667491686359904, 0.9689939767213887, 0.9872801673373786, 0.9786773752322605, 0.9889003372198818], [0.9522423474912594, 0.9058183417109515, 0.9251948438121138, 1.0, 0.9299880514954331, 0.8633016543725155, 0.8480159549979944, 0.8846832119506772, 0.8549651220805452, 0.8625840477854568], [0.9924537684077833, 0.9720042335801492, 0.9922213493721925, 0.9299880514954331, 1.0, 0.9286669208701384, 0.9333471169337565, 0.9608763731749859, 0.9493255688093539, 0.9761062630584328], [0.8895864607254809, 0.8236054328646096, 0.9667491686359904, 0.8633016543725155, 0.9286669208701384, 1.0, 0.9980284463169727, 0.994348065667556, 0.993861166093055, 0.9695176223678753], [0.8911800123689296, 0.8311148112692656, 0.9689939767213887, 0.8480159549979944, 0.9333471169337565, 0.9980284463169727, 1.0, 0.9957851054969118, 0.9982181534658013, 0.9791400659545252], [0.9273022835638276, 0.873310656326527, 0.9872801673373786, 0.8846832119506772, 0.9608763731749859, 0.994348065667556, 0.9957851054969118, 1.0, 0.9978737256112197, 0.9885554512243394], [0.9093065295855488, 0.8563983095457245, 0.9786773752322605, 0.8549651220805452, 0.9493255688093539, 0.993861166093055, 0.9982181534658013, 0.9978737256112197, 1.0, 0.989447655967652], [0.942937484839194, 0.9095079241006527, 0.9889003372198818, 0.8625840477854568, 0.9761062630584328, 0.9695176223678753, 0.9791400659545252, 0.9885554512243394, 0.989447655967652, 1.0]])
```

Could anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because $\sqrt{K^2}$ is not the matrix whose entries are the square root of those of $K^2$, but the matrix such that $\left(\sqrt{K^2}\right)^2=K^2$. You can compute this matrix by, for instance, performing an SVD decomposition on your matrix using `numpy`, like this:

```
import numpy as np

def geometric_difference(kernel_1, kernel_2):
    u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(kernel_2, hermitian=True)
    sqrt_k2 = u @ np.diag(np.sqrt(s)) @ v
    return np.sqrt(np.linalg.norm(sqrt_k2 @ np.linalg.inv(kernel_1) @ sqrt_k2, np.inf))
```

Applying this function on the matrix you provided yields `1.0000000010916217`. Note that it is also possible, and potentially faster, to compute $\sqrt{K^2}$ using the [scipy.linalg.sqrtm function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.sqrtm.html).

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I was able to reproduce your number `1.0000000010916217`. Out of curiosity, I normalized the input matrix using `normalize(kernel_1, axis=1, norm='l1')` before passing it into `geometric_difference()` and got `505.20041904170046` instead of `~1`. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by the `normalize` function here but its customary to rescale an $m\times m$ kernel matrix $K$ such that $\text{Tr}(K) = m$ (or $K_{ii}=1, i=1\dots m$); this is also the normalization the authors apply in the text.

Comment: @OmarShehab To add on @forky40's answer, your kernel is supposed to be Hermitian. You can look at the norm of M's columns with `np.linalg.norm(M, 1, axis=1)` which returns `[9.46552209, 9.09443527, 9.7183133 , 9.02679358, 9.63498965, 9.42766494, 9.44382364, 9.61001504, 9.52807361, 9.60669685]`. Thus, by applying the `normalize` function from `sklearn`, you won't divide each column by the same coefficient. Hence, the resulting matrix is not Hermitian anymore. If you *really* want to compute it despite this, remove the `hermitian=True` in the function, which returns `1.0284638009215255`.